# Infragistics WebDataGrid get value from a selected row by column name: VB.net to C# conversion

Tags: c#, infragistics, vb.net-to-c#

I'm in the process of converting a website with codebehind in VB.NET to C#. The only real problem I'm having is getting data from an Infragistics WebDataGrid row by column name in the `RowSelectionChanged` event.

Example VB.NET code:

```
If Me.WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Selection.SelectedRows(0).DataItem("Status").ToString <> "Released" Then
        '"Status" is the column name
End If
```

I figured changing it to this would pretty much do it, but to no avail.

```
if (this.WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Selection.SelectedRows[0].DataItem["Status"].ToString() != "Released") { 
        //do stuff
}
```

Specifically the error I get is, `Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'object'`, which I'm pretty positive is referring to the `DataItem["Status"]` part.

How do I go about getting the value from the selected row for a column specified by name?

UPDATE: I found a solution, which is in the answers below, but it could probably be done better. I'll gladly accept a different answer if a better one comes along.

Comment: In their documentation they're using Items instead of DataItem: http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/2011.1/CLR4.0/?page=WebDataGrid_Selection.html

I tried to see what the difference was, but using the search on their web page threw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that is missing from your C# line is a cast for this.WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Selection.SelectedRows[0].DataItem to DataRowView.  For example the following would work:

```
if (((DataRowView)this.WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Selection.SelectedRows[0].DataItem)["Status"].ToString() != "Released")
{
        //do stuff
}
```

Note that the following may be easier to read:

```
DataRowView drv = (DataRowView) this.WebDataGrid1.Behaviors.Selection.SelectedRows[0].DataItem;
if (drv["Status"].ToString() != "Released")
{
    //do stuff
}
```

I am assuming that the VB code that you are converting from worked because Option Strict wasn't set so the conversion between Object and DataRowView didn't need to be done explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution that works [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/t/56404.aspx), but it feels rather roundabout.

```
GridRecord selectedRow = e.CurrentSelectedRows[0];
DataRowView dataItem = (DataRowView)selectedRow.DataItem;
DataRow dataRow = dataItem.Row;
object[] valueArray = dataRow.ItemArray;
int columnIndex = WebDataGrid1.Columns["Status"].Index;
string statusValue = selectedRow.Items[columnIndex].Value.ToString();

if (statusValue != "Released") {
    //do stuff
}
```